# MediaPlayer setDataSource need best practice advice

Tags: android, media-player

After reading "[Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html)" and "[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)" android documentations I'm still confused and need experienced advice about [setDataSource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29) overloaded method.

I am using `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` component in my Project that is going to be a [foregroundService](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) while playing music. I have my music file(.mp3) in `res/raw` folder of my apk.
To start playing, I know I have to prepare the MediaPlayer object. Because Services in android applications by default uses single process and main thread, I don't want my users get [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)
while MediaPlayer prepares itself(think if media file in raw folder has a big size).
Then I use `prepareAsync` instead of `prepare`(Sync). So I can not use:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.myfile);
```

Because this already calls `prepare()` internally but not `prepareAsync()`.
So basically i have two options(two from four):

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.myfile);
mp.setDataSource(context, myUri);
```

or

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.myfile);
mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor());
afd.close();
```

after using one of them I can simple use:

```
mp.prepareAsync();
```

And finally my questions arise that "including these different methods, which one is the best option? Are there any benefits one over the other? Do i missing something?"

Comment: Personally, I like the last method, since it doesn't use strings in the code. I don't now if that counts as much of a "benefit", though.

Comment: @Geobits, avoiding constant strings in code is a good practice as i know but `FileDescriptor` is what android prefers for local files.Thanks for your comment. and i suggest you to read my comment on accepted answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't any real benefits to the various ways of calling `create` or `setDataSource`. The static `create` methods don't do much more than call `setDataSource` and `prepare`. The various `setDataSource` methods call each other internally. Eventually they boil down to two possible native calls, one with a string describing a remote URI and another with a local file descriptor. There may be a very slight performance advantage to creating the file descriptor yourself, but it will not be appreciable in context.

For local file playback, as you are demonstrating in your code, simply calling `prepare` (or the static `create` methods) isn't a bad practice at all. The underlying player should have no problem determining the relevant metadata and returning quickly no matter the size of the file. The `prepareAsync` method is more useful for network streams, where any number of situations might cause some unexpected delay. If you are designing a general purpose player, then using the `prepareAsync` method would be the way to go, but if you are simply playing raw assets it shouldn't make any difference. The variety of methods provided is simply a matter of convenience (take note of the javadoc for `create`).

Comment: after reading your answer, i looked into the [android framework](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) and understand what you telling. I saw the `private native void _setDataSource` methods and noticed `setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd, long offset, long length)` method is more common for local access. I roughly deduced `FileDescriptor`s for local and `Uri`s for remote(stream) purposes.