# How to Play All Audio file One by One when Click PLAY button 1 time

Tags: java, android, loops, audio

**I have two mp3 files. i want to play all mp3's one by one files when Click "Play" button.. *(Thats means after palyed 1st Audio , then need to play 2nd Audio file)***

I tried this code. but isn't working

```
 package com.example.playaudio;

  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.media.AudioManager;
  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.net.Uri;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int x,y ;
    x=R.raw.a;           //Mp3 file 1
    y=R.raw.b;           //Mp3 file 2          

    if (mp != null) {
        mp.release();
    }
    
    int z=0;
    
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++){            
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, x);
            mp.start();
         
        }
    }   

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(null!=mp){
        mp.release();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Please tell me solution for this problem

Answer (score 2):

Try to use While loop

```
    while(x<10){
        //code
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Mediaplayer's default constructor to get a handle of a Mediaplayer object then add all audio tracks to the playback queue.

```
MediaPlayer _myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
myPlayer.setDataSource( myContext , myURI);
myPlayer.start();


MediaPlayer _nextPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
nextPlayer.setDataSource( myContext , myNextURI);
myPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
```

Comment: what should be for "myContext"

Comment: It is the context on which the MediaPlayer is going to be run on, in your case it will just be "this" since you are playing the Mediaplayer on your Mainactivity.

Comment: What is The "myURI" and "myNextURI" in my case? Thank you KillaKem

Comment: "myURI" and "myNextURI" are URI's that reference your media.You need to use your resource ID's (R.raw.x and R.raw.y) to create URI's and then pass those URI's as arguments to the setDataSource method.To see how you can create URI's from resource ID's please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977809/mediaplayer-setdatasource-need-best-practice-advice