# How can I define file path in MediaPlayer.create() using variable? (Android)

Tags: java, android, path, media-player

How can I define file path in MediaPlayer.create() using variable?

I'am developing my first game for Android. My goal is to play different audio files during app execution. I have some files like:

-sound1.mp3 -sound2.mp3 -sound3.mp3

They are in my /res/raw/ project folder.

And I would like my code to be able to choose a file path.

For example (once not working):

```
for(int i=0; i>3; i++) { 
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound + "" + i;
mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass raw resources to `MediaPlayer.create()` use your application resource variable `R.raw.*`. For example:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), R.raw.sound1);
```

Please consider reading more about [Android Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html) because passing file paths of Resources doesn't make sense because Raw Resources are not stored as files.

Comment: I try to do this but my application stooped :

Comment: I try to do this but my application is stooped :                                  String num="1";
String raw_path="‪raw‬"+"."+"sound"+num;
       Uri path=Uri.parse(raw_path);

        mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),path);
        mp1.start();

Answer (score 0):

I suffered from the same problem.

But there is a good answer for it:

```
mediaPlayer.create(contex, variable uri)
```

You may have a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33086417/1305969).