# RecyclerView + MediaPlayer + Toggle Button + String Uri

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview

**Background:** I'm working on an Fitness app. Everything is working good till now but problem came when I was working with audio files `MediaPlayer` in android.

I have checked resources and found `ListView` but couldn't find anything on RecyclerView + MediaPlayer.

I want to know how to make it work while working with RecyclerView + Toggle Button + String Uri (Offline - Raw folder)

**Problem:** Right now it is playing the first .mp3 file on every click event (for Eng: *R.raw.sample_one_eng* is played and for Hindi: *R.raw.sample_one_hindi* is played). I think it is not taking int position into consideration.

Later, I would like to put it online (may be google cloud) since audio files (.mp3) are making my app quite heavy. Any ideas on that would be appreciated too (fast buffering, etc.).

**ListExercises.java**

```
public class ListExercises extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<ExerciseAudio> exerciseList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerViewAdapterAud adapter;
    PlayClickHandler clickHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_exercises);

        initData();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_ex);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterAud(exerciseList, getBaseContext());
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void initData() {

        exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_one, "Sample Exercise One", "Sans One",
                R.raw.sample_one_eng,
                R.raw.sample_one_hindi));

        exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_two, "Sample Exercise Two", "Sans Two",
                R.raw.sample_two_eng,
                R.raw.sample_two_hindi));

        exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_three, "Sample Exercise Three", "Sans Three",
                R.raw.sample_three_eng,
                R.raw.sample_three_hindi));

        exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_four, "Sample Exercise Four", "Sans Four",
                R.raw.sample_four_eng,
                R.raw.sample_four_hindi));
    }
}
```

**ViewExercise.java**

```
public class ViewExercise extends AppCompatActivity {

    int image_id, eng_aud_url, hindi_aud_url;
    String name, sans_name;

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    TextView timer, title, sansName;
    ImageView detail_image;
    ToggleButton tg_btn_speaker_eng, tg_btn_speaker_hindi;

    MediaPlayer mp;

    int position;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_exercise);

        Field[] field = R.raw.class.getFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++){
            arrayList.add(field[i].getName());
        }

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        sansName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sans_name);
        detail_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_image);

        tg_btn_speaker_eng = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tg_btn_speaker_eng);
        tg_btn_speaker_hindi = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tg_btn_speaker_hindi);

        tg_btn_speaker_eng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //toggleEnglish(tg_btn_speaker_eng.isChecked());
                int positionEng = 0;
                playSongEng(positionEng);
            }
        });

        tg_btn_speaker_hindi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //toggleHindi(tg_btn_speaker_hindi.isChecked());
                int positionHindi = 0;
                playSongHindi(positionHindi);
            }
        });

        if (getIntent() != null) {
            image_id = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_id", -1);
            name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            sans_name = getIntent().getStringExtra("sanskrit_name");

            detail_image.setImageResource(image_id);
            title.setText(name);
            sansName.setText(sans_name);
        }
    }


    public void playSongEng(int i) {
        //mp.reset();
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayList.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resId);
        mp.start();
    }

    public void playSongHindi(int i) {
        //mp.reset();
        int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(arrayList.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), resId);
        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mp != null)
            mp.release();
    }
}
```

This is how it looks!

**Edit (to avoid confusion):** Just noticed, that image name would have been **List Exercises** instead of **View Exercise** which corresponds to `ListExercises.java`

[image: List Exercise - RecyclerView]

And this one corresponds to `ViewExercise.java`

[image: View Exercise]

Thanks!

Comment: The `MediaPlayer` class will play mp3 from cloud also . For caching you need look for some Mechanism. Use a  Single Instance of `MediaPlayer` to play song inside `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Thanks @ADM Would be great if you can recommend any such caching Mechanism. Right now my `.mp3` are on an avg. 30 - 50 sec long. And I have close to 30*2 files appx. can be more in the future.

Comment: Use ExoPlayer it provide caching mechanism.

Comment: @RohitSharma from where you are getting this position in ListExcersice.java playSongEng(position); & playSongHindi(position); ?

Comment: @Sandy I have declared `int position` in ListExercise.java, also tried initializing it locally in the method, tried `ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();` also tried `Field[] field = R.raw.class.getFields();` array size is shown as 10 but still no luck. :( It always play zeroth element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also set the click listener inside `onBindViewHolder` without using any interface by setting the click listener on parent view of your *item_exercise_aud* layout like this:

```
holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewExercise.class);
            intent.putExtra("image_id", exerciseList.get(position).getImage_id());
            intent.putExtra("name", exerciseList.get(position).getName());
            intent.putExtra("sanskrit_name", exerciseList.get(position).getSanskrit_name());
            intent.putExtra("eng_aud_url", exerciseList.get(position).getEng_aud_url());
            intent.putExtra("hindi_aud_url", exerciseList.get(position).getHindi_aud_url());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Or you can refer [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9)

**Edit - 
To play the audio according to the recyclerview list's position, we have to send the raw file name of that particular exercise to the media player.**

Add two new variables to *ExerciseAudio* model class:

```
private String file_name_eng;
private String file_name_hindi;
```

Now modify the *initData* method as below:

```
private void initData() {

    exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_one, "Sample Exercise One", "Sans One",
            R.raw.sample_one_eng, R.raw.sample_one_hindi,
            "sample_one_eng", "sample_one_hindi"));

    exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_two, "Sample Exercise Two", "Sans Two",
            R.raw.sample_two_eng, R.raw.sample_two_hindi,
            "sample_two_eng", "sample_one_hindi"));

    exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_three, "Sample Exercise Three", "Sans Three",
            R.raw.sample_three_eng, R.raw.sample_three_hindi,
            "sample_three_eng", "sample_three_hindi"));

    exerciseList.add(new ExerciseAudio(R.drawable.sample_four, "Sample Exercise Four", "Sans Four",
            R.raw.sample_four_eng, R.raw.sample_four_hindi,
            "sample_four_eng", "sample_four_hindi"));
}
```

Now Modify the *ViewExercise* intent as:

```
intent.putExtra("file_name_eng", exerciseList.get(position).getFile_name_eng());
intent.putExtra("file_name_hindi", exerciseList.get(position).getFile_name_hindi());
```

Get the string extras in *ViewExercise* activity and send it to the `mediaplayer`:

```
file_name_eng = getIntent().getStringExtra("file_name_eng");
file_name_hindi = getIntent().getStringExtra("file_name_hindi");

For english:
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(file_name_eng, "raw", getPackageName());

For hindi:
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(file_name_hindi, "raw", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thanks @Nainal Is there any resource you can recommend that implements MediaPlayer + RecyclerView?

Comment: @RohitSharma Do you want to play the audio in recyclerview list?

Comment: no not recyclerview list. I had successfully implemented it on recyclerview list. I think my image name is interchanged it should be "List Exercises" which corresponds to "ListExercises.java" instead of "View Exercise" right now. I will edit it later. But the context of question remains the same.

Comment: Thanks @Nainal But, it's list, that's not my requirement. :(

Comment: Could you Please elaborate your requirement, actually its not clear from your question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code ..
add below dependency into app level gradle file..

```
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.3.0'
```

after that used below code ..

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExoPlayer.EventListener {

private SimpleExoPlayer mSimpleExoPlayer;

private SimpleExoPlayerView mSimpleExoPlayerView;

private Handler mMainHandler;
private AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory;
private TrackSelector mTrackSelector;
private LoadControl mLoadControl;
private DefaultBandwidthMeter mBandwidthMeter;
private DataSource.Factory mDataSourceFactory;
private SimpleCache mSimpleCache;
private DataSource.Factory mFactory;
private MediaSource mVideoSource;
private LoopingMediaSource mLoopingMediaSource;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private String videoUrl="http://sample.vodobox.net/skate_phantom_flex_4k/skate_phantom_flex_4k.m3u8";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);
    mSimpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.amPrgbrLoading);
}

/**
 * this method play audio and video with hls streaming.
 */
private void playMedia() {
    mMainHandler = new Handler();
    mBandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
    mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(mBandwidthMeter);
    mTrackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(mAdaptiveTrackSelectionFactory);

    mLoadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();
    mSimpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, mTrackSelector, mLoadControl);

    mSimpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(mSimpleExoPlayer);
    mSimpleExoPlayerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlaybackControlView.VisibilityListener() {
        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            mSimpleExoPlayerView.showController();
        }
    });
    mDataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,Util.getUserAgent(this, "com.exoplayerdemo"), mBandwidthMeter);
    mSimpleCache = new SimpleCache(this.getCacheDir(), new LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor(1024 * 1024 * 10));
    mFactory = new CacheDataSourceFactory(mSimpleCache, mDataSourceFactory,0);
    mVideoSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUrl),
            mFactory, mMainHandler, new AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadStarted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs) {
            //Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Load Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCompleted(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {
            //Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Load Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadCanceled(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadError(DataSpec dataSpec, int dataType, int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs, long elapsedRealtimeMs, long loadDurationMs, long bytesLoaded, IOException error, boolean wasCanceled) {
            videoUrl=""; // define second url
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpstreamDiscarded(int trackType, long mediaStartTimeMs, long mediaEndTimeMs) {
           // Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Up stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDownstreamFormatChanged(int trackType, Format trackFormat, int trackSelectionReason, Object trackSelectionData, long mediaTimeMs) {
           // Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "Down Stream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    mLoopingMediaSource = new LoopingMediaSource(mVideoSource);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.prepare(mLoopingMediaSource);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    mSimpleExoPlayer.addListener(new ExoPlayer.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

            if (playbackState == ExoPlayer.STATE_BUFFERING) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

        }
    });



}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    playMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    stopMedia();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMedia();
}

private void stopMedia() {
    mSimpleExoPlayer.stop();
    mSimpleExoPlayer.release();
}



@Override
public void onTimelineChanged(Timeline timeline, Object manifest) {

}

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {

}

@Override
public void onLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {

}

@Override
public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {

}

@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {

}
```

}

in this code used for video you can pass yor audio file path..

xml code..

```
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoPlayer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />
```

Comment: Thanks @AndroidTeam I believe you have answered my 2nd part of the question, also my requirement is not setting `private String Url` I want to put it from my Raw folder for now and later from google cloud, but it will be done through RecyclerView since I have multiple mp3 files, so if you can help/recommend or the logic on how to do it.

Comment: Exoplayer doesn't work when it's come to playing Youtube video's. It is much easier to implement youtube api through Google Docs. 

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1296

Answer (score 2):

You should design the ViewHolder of the RecyclerView in such a way that it should hold all the data required for the recycler view to work. For e.g

```
ExcerciseViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
 public int uriEnglish;  //To be replaced by URL/URI later on
 public int uriHindi; //To be replaced by URL/URI later on
 public View englishButton;
 public View hindiButton;
}
```

Your activity should implement an interface in the form of

```
public interface PlayClickHandler {
public playInstruction(int uriID);
}
```

Your adapter should be something like this:

```
public class ExerciseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExerciseViewHolder> {
    PlayClickHandler clickHandler;
    public ExerciseAdapter(PlayClickHandler clickHandler){
        this.clickHandler = clickHandler;
    }
    ...
    public onBindViewHolder(ExerciseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ExcerciseViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.hindiButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
           clickHandler.playInstruction(finalHolder.uriHindi);
           }
        })
    }
}
```

Your Activity should be implementing this interface and provide the functionality for playback using a single instance of MediaPlayer.

Following the idea in the above code, I believe you should be able to achieve what you want. Please feel free to ask if you are not clear on any point.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul I liked the idea. But the problem is my interface is defined as `void onClick(View view, int position);` and 2nd thing is I don't want it on `onBindViewHolder` I want it on `holder.setItemClickListener`