# how to prevent mediaplayer to overlapping audio?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer

i was building a button for playing my music but there is a problem, i am building this project with recyclerview and i want it that if i pressed button for music 1, and then i pressed the button for music 2, the music 1 is stopped. here's what i try

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val item = dataset[position]
    var buton = false
    holder.textview.text = context.resources.getString(item.stringid)
    holder.quotes.text = context.resources.getString(item.quotesid)
    holder.namalagu.text = context.resources.getString(item.laguid)

    holder.button.setOnClickListener {
        if (!holder.lagu.isPlaying && !buton){
           holder.lagu = MediaPlayer.create(context, item.fileLaguid)
           holder.lagu.start()
           holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.pause, 0, 0, 0)
           holder.button.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.pause)
            buton = true
       }
       else if (holder.lagu.isPlaying && !buton){ <- this is the part where i try implement those feature
            holder.lagu.stop()
            holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.play, 0, 0, 0)
            holder.button.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.play)
            buton = true
        }
       else{
           holder.lagu.pause()
           holder.button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.play, 0, 0, 0)
           holder.button.text = context.resources.getString(R.string.play)
            buton = false
       }
    }
```

i tried searching it from google but still no answer, i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use one `MediaPlayer` for your list (instead of one per item).
But you will need to keep track of you player's state.

When the button is clicked anywhere in the list you first of all stop the player (if something is currently playing). Next you reset the player and set the new data source. Finally, you prepare and start the player.

And don't forget to release the player in the end.

Comment: well i found more problem in the datasource part, my raw file is int but the data source want uri, do you have an answer for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086417/mediaplayer-setdatasourcestring-not-working-with-local-files